# Header doesn't appear with the assigned dimensions

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a page with html and css . this page there is a header in the mobile version has a height of 80px and the PC version has a height of 150px and within the heading is a logo in the mobile version has a height of 70px and a width of 250px and version pc 85px 300px . The problem is that when I open the page in Firefox and inspect the header elements and logo has lower dimensions ace assigned , although the programmer tools appear validated the assigned dimensions.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  min-width:300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.Wrapper {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative; background-color: #fff;
}
header{
  background: rgba(51,20,10,0.95);
}
/* Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 979px) {
  header{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
  }
  a.logo{
    background-image:url(Logo_M.png);
    width:250px;
    height:70px;
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%); 
  }
}
/* PC */    
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  header{
    width:980px;
    height:150px;
  }
  a.logo{
    background-image:url(Logo_L.png);
    width:300px;
    height:85px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:56px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <header>
    <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check your top and left; because of which your logo is going left and you can't see that portion of logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. A few things I would suggest :

- stick to a naming convention when assigning class names, capitalized
  class names aren't a popular choice
- care about css specificity, it will come back and haunt you when
  doing media queries as you will be in danger of overwriting styles
- avoid using position absolute when doing responsive websites
- you don't need "display:block" and "width:100%" at the same time,
  display block already sets the width to 100%
- avoid assigning both width and height to images, it can lead to image
  stretching

I would tackle your problem this way :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 980px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-header {
  background:rgba(51,20,10,0.95);
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


@media(max-width:980px) {
  .main-header {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .main-header__logo {
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <header class="main-header">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="main-header__logo" src="http://placehold.it/300x80" alt="logo" />
    </a>
  </header>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this pushes you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on Firefox 47.0 for Ubuntu. It seems ok,on mobile the logo is 250px/70px